# More concise jQuery if/else for input validation

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm using the Payment.js plugin to format and validate credit card input fields. I need to validate client-side on keyup/focusout, and again after the server submit returns an error message. I want the error styling to be specific to the field that's invalid. My code is working the way I want it to, but I would like it to be more efficient/concise. Any advice is greatly appreciated!

```
$(function() {
    // Initiate payment.js plugin
    $('.cc-num').payment('formatCardNumber');
    $('.cc-exp').payment('formatCardExpiry');
    $('.cc-cvc').payment('formatCardCVC');

    // Toggle error styling
    $toggleErrorStyling = function(el, erred) {
        var inputContainer = $(el).parents('.input-container');
        if (erred) {
            inputContainer.addClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success');
        } else {
            inputContainer.removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
        }
    };

    // Validate each form field
    $('.paymentInput').bind('focusout', function() {
        var valid,
            erred = function(valid) {},
            $hdnCCType = $('input[id$="hdnCCType"]'),
            $cardType = $.payment.cardType($('.cc-num').val()),
            $errorMsg = $('.alert-danger');

        if ($(this).hasClass('cc-num')) {
            valid = $.payment.validateCardNumber($(this).val());
            if (valid) {
                $hdnCCType.val($cardType); // set the hidden value to post back to the Server
            }
        } else if ($(this).hasClass('cc-exp')) {
            // validate expiry date
            valid = $.payment.validateCardExpiry($('.cc-exp').payment('cardExpiryVal'));
        } else if ($(this).hasClass('cc-cvc')) {
            //validate security code
            valid = $.payment.validateCardCVC($('.cc-cvc').val(), $cardType);
        }

        $errorMsg.hide();
        erred(valid);
        $toggleErrorStyling(this, !valid);
    });

    // After form submit,
    // if .alert-danger is visible on the page,
    // validate all three inputs,
    // but return error styling only on the invalid ones,
    // and ignore hash marks on browser back from verify ?edit=T
    if ($(".alert-danger").is(":visible")) {
        var $cardType = $.payment.cardType($('.cc-num').val());

        if (!$.payment.validateCardNumber($('.cc-num').val())) {
            $toggleErrorStyling($('.cc-num'), true);
        } else {
            $toggleErrorStyling($('.cc-num'), false);
        }

        if (!$.payment.validateCardExpiry($('.cc-exp').payment('cardExpiryVal'))) {
            $toggleErrorStyling($('.cc-exp'), true);
        } else {
            $toggleErrorStyling($('.cc-exp'), false);
        }

        if (!$.payment.validateCardCVC($('.cc-cvc').val(), $cardType)) {
            $toggleErrorStyling($('.cc-cvc'), true);
        } else {
            $toggleErrorStyling($('.cc-cvc'), false);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: The code you posted is invalid: it has one more closing brace than opening. And so it is not clear how to interpret it.

Comment: Thank you; I think something went awry with the CTRL+K shortcut. I have re-formatted.

Comment: This question could be suitable for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help), as long as (a) your code works as intended, (b) your code is real code, rather than example code, and (c) your code is included in the body of the question. If you wish for a peer review to improve all aspects of your code, please post it on Code Review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some ideas on how to make your code more concise:

1) Replace `if (cond) do(true) else do(false)` patterns with `do(cond)` pattern

So in the `$toggleErrorStyling` function do:

```
inputContainer.addClass('has-error').toggleClass('has-success', !erred);
```

And in the `if ($(".alert-danger").is(":visible"))` block do:

```
$toggleErrorStyling($('.cc-num'), !$.payment.validateCardNumber($('.cc-num').val()));
$toggleErrorStyling($('.cc-exp'), !$.payment.validateCardExpiry($('.cc-exp').payment('cardExpiryVal')));
$toggleErrorStyling($('.cc-cvc'), !$.payment.validateCardCVC($('.cc-cvc').val(), $cardType));
```

2) Instead of the `if (a) value = x else if (b) value = y else value = z` pattern, use the ternary operator: `value = a ? x : b ? y : z`

So assign to `value` as follows:

```
valid = $(this).hasClass('cc-num')
    // set the hidden value to post back to the Server
    ? $.payment.validateCardNumber($(this).val()) && $hdnCCType.val($cardType)
    : $(this).hasClass('cc-exp')
        // validate expiry date
        ? $.payment.validateCardExpiry($('.cc-exp').payment('cardExpiryVal'))
        // *** cc-cvc is only possible class left, so no need to test it
        //validate security code
        : $.payment.validateCardCVC($('.cc-cvc').val(), $cardType);
```

As the `&&` can produce a non-boolean truthy value, you may need to change the call to `erred` so you really pass a boolean:

```
erred(!!valid);
```

As the implementation of that function was empty, I don't know if you really need this change.